# Cartesian product of nonempty closed convex subsets of R is a polyhedral

Tags: real-analysis

I want to prove that for a finite number of $\mathcal{X}_i\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ that are nonempty, closed and convex, the set $\prod_{i} \mathcal{X}_i$ is a polyhedral set.

My solution: $\mathbb{R},(-\infty,b],[a,b],[a,+\infty),\{a\}$ for any $a<b$ are all the candidates for $\mathcal{X}_i$. All of these candidates are polyhedral sets, thus $\prod_{i} \mathcal{X}_i$ is a polyhedral set too.

Is this solution correct?

Thanks for your time!

EDIT: The definition that I'm using for polyhedral is $\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n:Ax\leq b,\ Cx=d\}$ for some matrices $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n},C\in\mathbb{R}^{\ell\times n}$ and vectors $b\in\mathbb{R}^m,d\in\mathbb{R}^\ell$.

Comment: "thus $\prod_i \mathcal{X}_i$ is a polyhedral set too." Why?

Comment: How is a 'polyhedral set' defined? Anyway, I guess you could use induction.

Comment: I added the definition that I'm using. I think induction gives the answer, but I was wondering if there are any other candidates for closed convex sets in $\mathbb{R}$ that I missed.

Comment: No, you don't miss any: consider the infimum and the supremum of the given closed convex set. By closedness, these are included in the set (unless they're $\pm\infty$), and by convexity, the set must contain the full interval.